# Azure Grant admin consent for Arcadis not editable

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-api-apps

I have added Graph permissions that "User.ReadWrite.All" and other permissions like below, but I am not able to grant consent permission for the added requests. Even my organization's azure support team members also not able to give me permission. Why the "Grant admin consent for Arcadis" button is not enabled? Why is it showing "Not granted for Arcadis? Need to pay for this API consumption or How to enable this feature?

[image]

Comment: You need an admin role in the tenant to click that. Does the support team have that?

Comment: @Juunas, No, even My support team does not have the admin role. So how to enable that? Need to ask Microsoft ?

Answer (score 1):

To grant consent to these permissions, the signed-in user must be granted the [Company Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#global-administrator--company-administrator), [Application Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#application-administrator), or [Cloud Application Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#cloud-application-administrator) directory roles in Azure AD.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent

You can view directory roles and directory role assignments in the Azure portal, under Azure Active Directory > Roles and administrators.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-manage-roles-portal